# Delete every self installed material and reset ubuntu to default without reinstallation

Tags: 14.04, restore, default, reset

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and while I was playing with the files and the terminal, I destroyed my system.(Destroyed means Software Center got deleted, Lazarus(IDE for pascal programming language) got deleted, Update does not work, WINE got vanished, All is messed up. And I am unable to install or run softwares). Now what I want to do is to restore everything. All my data(even data from home, downloads etc.) shall be deleted and I once again come to possess a working system as I had it before with only default softwares. To be frank, I am using Zorin OS 9 but it is same thing as ubuntu 14.04. Architecture is same, only display is different(and I have installed it just for its good display).

So, is there anyway to reset the operating system without reinstalling from USB device. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to just "reset" the OS like you can with Windows 8. You can probably reinstall the core packages though.

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to reinstall? It would be easier and quicker to back up your personal data if you need to, and then do a fresh installation.

Comment: @CarlH  Ah!! My system got crashed. No GUI. only terminal is working. I will need installation disc for installing ubuntu and for that I will have to download it. As system is not working in GUI mode and I am not so expert to handle it in command mode. Therefore, I thought to recover it so that display comes again and everything settles up. Thanks for comments!!

Comment: I suggest to install a desktop environment and then reboot into it and use that to download and burn an installation disc. For example,  `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`  And then do a fresh installation.

Comment: @CarlH In case of above command I get error which says that the package has unmet dependencies and that it requires software-center, xorg, zenity, update manager. And I have already said that all these are deleted! Any further Suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit installation disc from the command line, follow these steps.

Download the install disc image.

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Identify your DVD drive.

```
wodim --devices
```

Your drive is given after `dev=/dev/` e.g. sr0

Burn the image to disk (replace NNN with your device, that you found in the previous step)

```
wodim -tao speed=1 -eject dev=/dev/NNN -v -data ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Comment: A great one but I need some more details. I don't have DVD drive in my PC (as it didn't come in my system). So how should I replace the commands for making a bootable usb which is mounted as sdb1 in /media/usb. (Ticking this right because it must work for people having a dvd drive.)

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself, but hopefully it will be helpful for you, and if not, somebody else will be able to give a better answer.

For a bootable USB device, **the disk must be unmounted**

Then use `dd` to put the disk image onto the USB disk. (Replace NNN with your disk's name, as found with `wodim --devices`).

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/NNN bs=1M
```

Comment: Thank u friend.  You know I have asked this question 12 hours ago! I am having the error since 14 hours ago (A long time!). Now I am going to give it a try. I will must inform you about proceedings and happenings. May it work. Thank you as usual.